# Reuseable component cause Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So i'm trying to use re useable component. Here is the script `Button.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../components/styles';

class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onPress = this.props.onPress;
    this.title = this.props.title;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.onPress}
        style={styles.appButtonContainer_login}>
        <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>{this.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default MyButton;
```

here is my `app.js`

```
const App = () => {
  setInterval(() => RNBootSplash.hide(), 1000);
  return <MainStackNavigator />;
};

export default App;
```

my `MainStackNavigator`

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function MainStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          options={{headerShown: false}}
          component={WelcomeScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          options={{headerTitleAlign: 'center', headerLeft: null}}
          component={LoginScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Register"
          options={{headerTitleAlign: 'center', headerLeft: null}}
          component={RegisterScreen}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default MainStackNavigator;
```

and here is my `WelcomeScreen`

```
export default function WelcomeScreen({navigation}) {
  const handle_navigation = (name) => {
    navigation.navigate(name);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Image
          style={styles.header_image}
          source={require('../assets/bootsplash_logo.png')}
        />
        <Text style={styles.headline}>Welcome</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Ini lagi belajar react native</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.button_container}>
        <MyButton onPress={handle_navigation('Login')} title="Login" />
        <MyButton onPress={handle_navigation('Register')} title="Register" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

when i run it i get this error message

> Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a
> different component.

when i remove `MyButton` from `WelcomeScreen` there is no error. So i think thats the one cause the error. How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onPress` prop of `MyButton`/`TouchableOpacity` needs a function variable passed to it. However, you are passing the result of the function call `handle_navigation`, which is void.

A simple fix is to change `handle_navigation` so it returns a function:

```js
const handle_navigation = (name) => {
  return () => navigation.navigate(name);
};
```

You could also pass an arrow function directly to the `onPress` prop, which IMHO is a bit clearer:

```
<View style={styles.button_container}>
  <MyButton onPress={() => handle_navigation('Login')} title="Login" />
  <MyButton onPress={() => handle_navigation('Register')} title="Register" />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use functional component rather than class component in MyButton
like

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../components/styles';

const MyButton = props => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={props.onPress}
      style={styles.appButtonContainer_login}
    >
      <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default MyButton;
```

May be this will help you.

and in welcome screen

```
<MyButton onPress={() => handle_navigation('Login')} title="Login" />
<MyButton onPress={() => handle_navigation('Register')} title="Register" />
```